# How to detect live changes on TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, textfield, swiftui

I have a simple TextField that binds to the state 'location' like this,

```
TextField("Search Location", text: $location)
```

I want to call a function each time this field changes, something like this:

```
TextField("Search Location", text: $location) {
   self.autocomplete(location)
}
```

However this doesn't work. I know that there are callbacks, onEditingChanged - however this only seems to be triggered when the field is focussed.

How can I get this function to call each time the field is updated?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can create a binding with a custom closure, like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var location: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
            self.location
        }, set: {
            self.location = $0
            // do whatever you want here
        })

        return VStack {
            Text("Current location: \(location)")
            TextField("Search Location", text: binding)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi kontiki! Just a question about your interesting answer (I had never thought to use `Binding` that way): I was wondering why if I attach a didSet on the `location` var the didSet doesn't get called at all. Something like `@State var location: String = "" { didSet { //do something }}` I don't get why the function doesn't get called. Thank you.

Comment: didSet on location never triggers, because what you are changing through the binding, is location.wrappedValue, not location.

Comment: Great solution for adjusting from the textFieldDidChange() in SwiftUI thank you!

Comment: I get the _Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type_

Comment: trying to add return to body - can not, says _Binding<String> needs to conform to View_

Comment: There is one problem with this solution: it triggers the view body to be recreated on every text change

Comment: Recreate view is very lightweight in SwiftUI, so this drawback is still acceptable as we don't have textFieldDidChange - yet. Don't forget to return your body if you get "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements" error

Comment: Thanks  what a great solution! I've used it to perform an action when textfield count >= 9

Comment: The `set` closure is called three times with every stroke.

Answer (score 121):

## SwiftUI 2.0

From iOS 14, macOS 11, or any other OS contains SwiftUI 2.0, there is a new modifier called `.onChange` that detects any change of the given `state`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var location: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Your Location", text: $location)
            .onChange(of: location) {
                print($0) // You can do anything due to the change here.
                // self.autocomplete($0) // like this
            }
    }
}
```

---

#### SwiftUI 1.0

For older iOS and other SwiftUI 1.0 platforms, you can use `onReceive`:

```
.onReceive(location.publisher) { 
    print($0)
}
```

<sub>**Note that** it returns **the change** instead of the entire value. If you need the behavior the same as the `onChange`, you can use the **combine** and follow the answer provided by @pawello2222.</sub>

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work for a TextFIeld in an alert to limit the number of characters that can be set in that textField?

Answer (score 49):

Another solution, if you need to work with a `ViewModel`, could be:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var location = "" {
        didSet {
            print("set")
            //do whatever you want
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search Location", text: $viewModel.location)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @superpuccio, if you are going to use a ViewModel, you could just put the code in didSet { ... }. No need for: cancellable/sink. ;-)

Comment: This is a cleaner answer than the accepted, IMO. It could get messy fast if you have multiple bindings within your body var.

Comment: Does it need to be an observable object?

Comment: @Zorayr yes, otherwise you won’t get updates on Published properties.

Comment: @superpuccio - Can you take a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047679/how-to-solve-deadlock-on-multiple-published-on-2-textfield-in-swiftui

Comment: ObservedObject will be recreated when redraw. So the text will lost after redraw.

Comment: @FrankCheng Observed objects are not recreated when your view gets redrawn (i.e. when the body of your view is requested again). They are recreated when your view is inside another view's body and that view gets redrawn (i.e. its body is requested again, in that body there's your child view containing the observed object, so your view is entirely recreated with all its properties, including your observed object). If this is your case you should inject the observed object in your view from the outside or, if you can make use of iOS 14, try the new StateObject which is meant exactly for this.

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't use View Models

Comment: Just a small thing, The SwiftUI framework includes Combine. So "import Combine" isn't needed.

Answer (score 23):

### iOS 13+

Use `onReceive`:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var location: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search Location", text: $location)
            .onReceive(Just(location)) { location in
                // print(location)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a very nice, clean and clever way of doing this!

Comment: Does this actually work?

Wouldn't you need Just(location) to be stored somewhere to subscribe to it and receive its values?

Comment: @Xaxxus It works perfectly fine. I encourage you to try it yourself.

Comment: @pawello2222 I ended up needing to so something a bit different for my use case.

I have a textfield that has an error label underneath it. The error label only needs to show if there is an error. And the validation to trigger that error label needs to run on keystroke (with a 300 ms) debounce.

So what I ended up doing was making an observable object view model for my textfield. With a text and errorText published properties

And I .onRecieve(viewModel.$text.debounce(300, runloop.main)) the $text variable to trigger my validation with a .debounce works like a charm.

Comment: Best method! This also works on MacOs by the way :)

Answer (score 14):

While other answers work might work but this one worked for me where I needed to listen to the text change as well as react to it.

first step create one **extension function**.

```
extension Binding {
    func onChange(_ handler: @escaping (Value) -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(
            get: { self.wrappedValue },
            set: { newValue in
                self.wrappedValue = newValue
                handler(newValue)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

now call **change** on the binding in **TextField** something like below.

```
  TextField("hint", text: $text.onChange({ (value) in
      //do something here
  }))
```

source : [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange)

Answer (score 5):

What I found most useful was that TextField has a property that is called onEditingChanged which is called when editing starts and when editing completes.

```
TextField("Enter song title", text: self.$userData.songs[self.songIndex].name, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
    if changed {
        print("text edit has begun")
    } else {
        print("committed the change")
        saveSongs(self.userData.songs)
    }
})
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .font(.largeTitle)
```

Comment: The onEditingChanged is NOT called when the text changes, but when editing starts or stops. So called once when you tap inside the text field, then called next when you hit Done.  And it does work that way.  If you're looking for something called on each keystroke, this isn't it.  But it's a perfectly good solution, for what it is.

Comment: The question specifically is about when the text changes, not for when editing starts/stops. This is an incorrect answer for this question.

Comment: Oh, you are correct.  Useful but not what they were asking.