# SwiftUI Textfields and Ints

Tags: swiftui

I started today to use SwiftUI an I want to code a small calculator. Therefore I want a textfield where the user can write a number. But the usual textfields only accepts strings
what can I do ?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string to Int? Because "usual textfields" accept numbers as well, just as a string, not int. You will need to convert the string to an int by `Int(myString)`, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - How to create TextField that only accepts numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733003/swiftui-how-to-create-textfield-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the `TextField` keyboard to be numeric, just do this:

```
TextField("Input", text: $input)
    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

where the `keyboardType` is a [`UIKeyboardType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype).

Comment: You still can *paste* some text with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

with SwiftUI 2.0 you could use something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var theInt: Int?
@State var text = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("enter a number", text: $text)
            .onChange(of: text) {
              let txt = $0.filter { "-0123456789".contains($0) }
              if allowed(txt) {
                 theInt = Int(txt)
                 text = txt
              } else {
                text = String(txt.dropLast())
              }
            }
    }
}

func allowed(_ str: String) -> Bool {
    let num = str.starts(with: "-") ? String(str.dropFirst()) : str
    return CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: num))
}
}
```