# SwiftUI: "Fatal error: Index out of range" within the `onReceive` action *after* removing the item from an array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI so apologies if I don't explain myself properly.

I am trying to display a list of School class modules. Within each of these modules, I want to display a list of students where I can edit their names via a `TextField`.

Here's what my data structure looks like:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var classModules: [ClassModule] = [
        // ...
    ]
}
struct ClassModule: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var students: [Student]
}

struct Student: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}
```

In my view, I use a `ForEach` to display each module, then within each module, I have another `ForEach` that displays the student. Each student has a `TextField` that has an `onReceive` action that intercepts text changes and sanitises it.

Additionally, I have a delete button next to the module. This deletes the entire module and all the students within it when pressed. When I press this, the item is removed by safely checking for a valid index. However, once this happens, I get an `Fatal error: Index out of range` error within the `onReceive` action of the Textfield. For some reason this is triggering for a piece of data that no longer exists.

Does anyone have an idea why this occurs? Below is a full code snippet that duplicates this issue. Simply tap the bottom 'Delete' button.

I'm using Xcode 15.0

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var classModules: [ClassModule] = [
        ClassModule(name: "Maths", students: [
            Student(name: "John"),
            Student(name: "Emma"),
            Student(name: "James")
        ]),
        ClassModule(name: "Science", students: [
            Student(name: "David"),
            Student(name: "Kerry"),
            Student(name: "Anna")
        ]),
        ClassModule(name: "Art", students: [
            Student(name: "Georgina"),
            Student(name: "Bob"),
            Student(name: "Fred")
        ])
    ]
    
}
struct ClassModule: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var students: [Student]
}

struct Student: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($viewModel.classModules) { $classModule in
            ClassModuleView(classModule: $classModule, remove: {
                print("Remove module pressed")
                if let index = viewModel.classModules.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == classModule.id }) {
                    viewModel.classModules.remove(at: index)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ClassModuleView: View {
    @Binding var classModule: ClassModule
    var remove: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(classModule.name)
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: remove, label: {
                    Text("Delete")
                })
            }
            Group {
                ForEach($classModule.students) { $student in
                    StudentView(student: $student)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StudentView: View {
    @Binding var student: Student
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField(value: $student.name)
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @Binding var value: String
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Rendering textfield: \(value)")
        TextField("", text: $value)
            .onReceive(Just(value)) {
                print("onReceive", $0)
                let newValue = $0
                if value != newValue {
                    value = newValue
                }
                
            }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: `.onReceive(Just(value))` looks like a weird hack, what are you trying to do? FYI your model store should be init as `@StateObject` not `@ObservedObject`. It's odd to name it  `ViewModel` because in SwiftUI the `View` structs are the view models.

Comment: OnReceive seems to be the recommended way to modify input text to prevent unwanted characters. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733003/how-to-create-textfield-that-only-accepts-numbers

Comment: Also I was using ObservedObject because I was passing the view model as an environment object in my actual project, this code was written to highlight the error. However I will try StateObject and see if that changes anything

Comment: It seems that when you do `viewModel.classModules.remove(at: index)` in ContentView, 
it triggers the  `Just(value)` publisher, but it no longer has an existing `value`. 
At the link you show, there are also solutions without using Combine, just using `.onChange(of: value)`, and that does work 
in your case.

Comment: Can confirm switching to `.onChange` fixes the issue.

Why would anyone choose `onReceive` over the `onChange`? It's the most recommended way from most sources online but has this major "gotcha" that's not mentioned anywhere. I can't imagine my use-case is an uncommon scenario.

Anyway thanks I appreciate it :)

Comment: onChange was added in later version of SwiftUI. It was actually just updated to allow it to also be called for the first value.

Comment: what is the `the major "gotcha"` when using `.onChange`?

Comment: Sorry I'm talking about the `onReceive`. `onChange` works perfectly

Comment: The "gotcha" I'm referring to is `onReceive` triggering after the data is deleted - which causes the fatal `index out of range` error