# How to set the text only digit with one point in the dynamic textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

When I have typed a few characters in the textfield and then the new character that has been added has been deleted from it, it is sent to the server and the entire amount that has been added is sent and is deleted without deleting the textfield and the value and prompt are dynamic so that I am not able to find out, I am getting only digit and only one point.

```
TextField("", text: Binding(
    get: { userMeasurements[index.id].stringValue },
    set: { newValue in
    
   var updatedValue = newValue
   updatedValue = updatedValue.filter { ".0123456789".contains($0) }
   userMeasurements[index.id] = JSON(newValue)
   let measurement = Measurement(measurement: index.id, value: newValue.filter       { ".0123456789".contains($0) })
    if !modifiedMeasurements.contains(measurement) {
        modifiedMeasurements.append(measurement)
     }
  }), prompt: Text(index.desc).font(Font.custom("Agency FB", size: 16))
         .foregroundColor(Constants.LightWhite))
   .digitswithPointOnly(text: Binding<String>(
                                    get: { userMeasurements[index.id].stringValue },
                                    set: { newValue in
                                        userMeasurements[index.id] = JSON(newValue)
                                        let measurement = Measurement(measurement: index.id, value: newValue)
                                    }
                                ))
```

And this is my extension for decimal value

```
extension TextField where Label == Text {
    func digitswithPointOnly(text: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        self.keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .onChange(of: text.wrappedValue) { newValue in
                var filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0) } 
                let decimalCount = filtered.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == "." ? 1 : 0) }
                 if decimalCount > 1 {
                      filtered.removeLast()
                    
  } else if let index = filtered.firstIndex(of: ".") {let fractionalPart = filtered[filtered.index(after: index)...]
}
   if filtered != text.wrappedValue {
     text.wrappedValue = filtered
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I am using xcode 14 for ios 17 and design for iPad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create TextField that only accepts numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733003/how-to-create-textfield-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: @lazarevzubov I tried but it is not working my textfield data come from server response and send to the server.

Comment: Separation of concerns, keep your text field logic as simple as possible and handle anything that is related to what you get or send to the server elsewhere. Don't try to solve everything in one place.