# How to solve deadlock on multiple Published on 2 TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, publish, combine

I have two Published state in my viewmodel one is for `source` and another one is for `destination`

Based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878202/213532) to detect live changes on textfield. I have implemented like this

```
TextField("", text: $viewModel.source)
TextField("", text: $viewModel.destination)
```

Problem, here is i need to update the either fields whenever user enter some value. For example - If user enter on `source` then i need to update `destination` with source inputs. And if user input `destination` then need to update `source`.

```
@Published var source: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            destination = source / rate
        }
    }
```

This is just one solution. I have to repeat it same for destination then it will create deadlock

```
@Published var destination: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            source = destination * rate
        }
    }
```

How to solve this problem ? Only solution i imagine if there is any way i can get live changes in the form of callback then i can update the either field but i don't know if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
class SourceDestinationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let rate: Double = 2 // just for demo
    
    @Published var source: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            let newValue = source / rate
            if destination != newValue {
                destination = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    @Published var destination: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            let newValue = destination * rate
            if source != newValue {
                source = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestDependentFields: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = SourceDestinationViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: Binding<String>(get: { String(self.vm.source) },
                set: { self.vm.source = ($0 as NSString).doubleValue }))
            TextField("", text: Binding<String>(get: { String(self.vm.destination) },
                set: { self.vm.destination = ($0 as NSString).doubleValue }))

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```