# Assign Custom TextField data in another View SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield

I am trying to assign credit card information(text: $data) through customTextField to another View.

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    @State var data : String = ""
    var tFtext: String = ""
    var tFImage: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
                Image(tFImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .padding()
                TextField(tFtext, text: $data)
                    .padding()
                    .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9647058824, green: 0.9725490196, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)))
    }
}
```

To this View called CardInfo

```
struct CardInfo : View {
    var creditCard: CreditCard
    @State var isSaved: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
                .textContentType(.givenName)
            creditCard.cardOwnerName = CustomTextField.text
```

But CustomTextField.text won't work. How can I pull those texts from textfield?[image]

Comment: This might help you as well: [How to detect live changes on TextField in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875550/how-to-detect-live-changes-on-textfield-in-swiftui)

Comment: This is another issue, please do not change the question when you apply some new code and new errors happen ;) Comment or Ask a new question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to drive the text from the parent, you should use a `Binding` instead of `State`:

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    @Binding var data: String
    ,,,
}
```

then you can access it from the parent as you wish like:

```
struct CardInfo : View {
    @State var isSaved: Bool = false
    @State private(set) var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
                .textContentType(.givenName)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, remember that you should not change any `State` from outside of the `body` block. (So you can make it `private(set)`)

And you can access it directly from the text:

```
creditCard.cardOwnerName = text
```

## BUT!

You can not set `creditCard.cardOwnerName = text` in the view builder as pawello mentioned. You should move this code somewhere it belongs to like `onChange` or `onReceive`. [Here is an example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63425994/5623035)

So take a look at this:

```
CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
    .onReceive(text.publisher, perform: { _ in
        print(text) // could be creditCard.cardOwnerName = text
    })
```

Comment: You may also need to explain *where* to set `creditCard.cardOwnerName = text`. In the question OP tried to use `creditCard.cardOwnerName = CustomTextField.text` in a `VStack`...

Comment: I have changed the answer to make it more like the original question. Thanks for mentioning that pawello :)

Comment: Unfortunately creditCard.cardOwnerName = text gives error.

Comment: @MertKöksal See [How to detect live changes on TextField in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875550/how-to-detect-live-changes-on-textfield-in-swiftui)

Comment: How do you say "but still I don't get it."? How are you checking that?  I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: Seems like you found the answer to your other question.  Let me know if you have issues with this so I can help you @MertKöksal

Comment: I did it. But now all my textfields are filling with the same texts. If I type ABC to name field, card number, cvv, card name are also gets ABC at the same moment.

Comment: You should define a separate `@State var text = ""` for each `TextField`. If. you connect all of them to the same `State`, they will be always the same

Comment: You are a miracle.

Comment: Hey @MertKöksal, don't forget to upvote if it helped you. And don't forget to mark it as answer if this is the answer to your question.